# giving all lambda function access to secretmanager

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I want to access aws secret manager in all my lambda functions(AWS::Serverless::Function). Currently, I have to give individual lambda function reference like below. Since I have many lambda functions it is tedious. I tried "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com" but it didn't work.

```
{
  "Version" : "2012-10-17",
  "Statement" : [ {
    "Effect" : "Allow",
    "Principal" : {
        "AWS" : ["arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/employer-api-getAllEmployeesFunctionRole-xxxxx/employer-api-4-getAllEmployeesFunction-xxxxx",
                 "arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxx:assumed-role/employee-backend-getEmployeeByIdFunctionRole-xxxxx/employee-backend-getEmployeeByIdFunction-xxxxx"
                ]
      },
    "Action" : "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    "Resource" : "*"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: The `Service` principal doesn't work, because it's not the lambda service that makes the call, but the role Lambda assumes. That means you need to add the role as a principal - can you try adding the role ARN with a wildcard? Something like this: `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/employe*`.

Comment: @Maurice I tried wildcard it didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You can create a policy(Like below) and attach it to your lambda's execution role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This will allow your lambda function to get secret value of any Secret stored in secret manager.

According to best practice we should only allow our lambda or any other aws service to give minimal access required.

So if your lambda needs access to only one Secret manager it is best you pass the ARN of that secret in below policy and attach it to your role.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
            "Resource": "<ARN of secret required by lambda>"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can use [AWS CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-iam-readme.html) IAM module to easily create role and policies.